# Find constants $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

> Find constants $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=0$.

**My attempt:** 
$\frac{x^2 + 1}{ x+1} -ax -b = \frac {x^2 +1 - (x +1)(ax+b)}{x+1}$
but then what?

Comment: But then : you divide  top and bottom by $x$, and try to send $x \to \infty$ now.

Comment: It's a common practice to find such constants (asymptotes). Firstly, to find $a$, you divide both sides by $x$. Then $\lim \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is what you need to find, and it's $a$. Then you calculate $\lim f(x)-ax$, and it's $b$. If one of those doesn't exists, then there's no asymptote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-1+2}{x+1}-ax+b\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x+1}+\frac{2}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\left(x-1-ax-b\right)$

From here we can find that $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: How did you get $a =1 $ and $b =-1?$

Comment: $lim\left((1-a)x-(1+b)\right)$

1-a=0, 1+b=0

Comment: why do you equate with 0, 1-a and 1+b?

Comment: if 1-a will equal zero than anything multiply by zeros equal zero this mean that (1-a)x equal zero no matter what x

Answer (score 2):

By long division,

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x-1+\frac2{x+1},$$ where the fraction is $o(1)$.